# FMDB resultset into dictionary

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

Is there an easy way to get the FMDB results of an `executeQuery:SELECT * ...` easily into a dictionary?

```
FMResultSet *appointmentResults = [[DataClass getDB] executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM Appointments WHERE date = ?",currDateString];
while ([appointmentResults next]) {
    //Create dictionary
    //Add dictionary to array for later use
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way I could make the dictionary keys the column names and the values the column values. Preferably without having to do a loop through every row inside the while.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yep:

```
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];

FMResultSet *appointmentResults = [[DataClass getDB] executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM Appointments WHERE date = ?",currDateString];
while ([appointmentResults next]) {
  [results addObject:[appointmentResults resultDictionary]];
}
```

`-resultDictionary` is a built-in method on `FMResultSet` that will turn the current tuple into an NSDictionary, keyed by column name.

Comment: Awesome! where did you get this? Looking at the FMDB documentation resultDict isn't on there.

Comment: @jostster it's in `FMResultSet.h`.

Comment: `-resultDict` is deprecated, use `-resultDictionary` instead.

Comment: @lucianf How will this handle a join query which will contain similar column names from two tables?

Comment: @ShaggyD Check out [the code](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/src/fmdb/FMResultSet.m), you won't be able to use `resultDictionary` in this case - just iterate through the column index as you know to expect the columns in the order you used in the join clause.

[Further confirmation](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/pull/212).