# FMDB Result of table to JSON object respecting the order of the columns.

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, fmdb

EDIT: NEW QUESTION AT BOTTOM It was getting all the rows I was wrong
I am trying to get the results of an SQL query and place them into a json object to send to my server to do more work with the data. Right now my code is only returning 1 row of data. Can anyone see any glaring mistakes?
IOS SIDE

```
- (void)sendLogin
{
NSError *jsonError;
NSData *requestdata;
//get login
NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tar.sqlite"];

FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
[database open];
FMResultSet *Loginresults = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM surveys"];
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
while ([Loginresults next]) {
    [results addObject:[Loginresults resultDictionary]];

    requestdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:results options:0 error:&jsonError];
}

[database close];




NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server/insert.php"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request;
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestdata length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:requestdata];

//this kicks off the request asynchronously
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

PHP SIDE

```
<?php
$foo = file_get_contents("php://input");

var_dump(json_decode($foo, true));

?>
```

Results from this

```
finish requesting: array(1) {
[0]=>
array(7) {
["desc"]=>
string(13) "matt the best"
["creator"]=>
string(7) "eric jr"
["synch"]=>
NULL
["name"]=>
string(4) "matt"
["sid"]=>
string(1) "1"
["datetime"]=>
string(3) "now"
["pid"]=>
string(1) "1"
}
}
```

Also I noticed my results for that table are not in the correct order. Is that working as intended? Is there any way to order this so it matches the order of the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Let me explain the solution. As you said in the comment, you are using the library throughout the app.

So, I think the best solution to your problem is create the [OrderedDictionary from CocoaWithLove](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html). The OrderedDictionary contains an NSMutableDictionary and an NSMutableArray for the keys inside it, to keep track of the order of the keys.

The you can create a Category of FMResultSet:

**FMResultSet+OrderedDict.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FMResultSet.h"
#import "OrderedDictionary.h"
@interface FMResultSet(OrderedDict)
- (OrderedDictionary*)resultOrderDictionary;
@end
```

**FMResultSet+OrderedDict.m**

```
#import "FMResultSet+OrderedDict.h"
#import "OrderedDictionary.h"
#import "FMDatabase.h"

@implementation FMResultSet(OrderedDict)

- (OrderedDictionary*)resultOrderDictionary {

    NSUInteger num_cols = (NSUInteger)sqlite3_data_count([_statement statement]);

    if (num_cols > 0) {
        OrderedDictionary *dict = [OrderedDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:num_cols];

        int columnCount = sqlite3_column_count([_statement statement]);

        int columnIdx = 0;
        for (columnIdx = 0; columnIdx < columnCount; columnIdx++) {

            NSString *columnName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlite3_column_name([_statement statement], columnIdx)];
            id objectValue = [self objectForColumnIndex:columnIdx];
            [dict setObject:objectValue forKey:columnName];
        }

        return dict;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Warning: There seem to be no columns in this set.");
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

And in your code do this:

```
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
    while ([Loginresults next]) {
        [results addObject:[Loginresults resultOrderDictionary]];
    }
    requestdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:results options:0 error:&jsonError];
```

If you want I can upload my Project Test to github.

EDIT: The [code](https://github.com/dcorbatta/StackoverflowTest) now is uploaded.

Comment: Great!! Thanks! I will try this and the other solution and post back to let you know what I did.

Comment: You're welcome. if you want, you can change the title of the question, so others persons with the same problem can find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiarized with **FMDatabase**. But I think that your problem is in the **while** statement:

```
FMResultSet *Loginresults = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM surveys"];
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
while ([Loginresults next]) {
    [results addObject:[Loginresults resultDictionary]];

    requestdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:results options:0 error:&jsonError];
}
```

You are overwriting the variable: requestdata with each result.

Maybe if you must change the code for this:

```
FMResultSet *Loginresults = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM surveys"];
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
while ([Loginresults next]) 
{
    [results addObject:[Loginresults resultDictionary]];
}
requestdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:results options:0 error:&jsonError];
```

Comment: Do you have an extension of FMResultSet? I am seeing https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb, and don't see the method resultDictionary.

Comment: Hey I follow this guide, http://www.brianjcoleman.com/framework-using-fmdb-to-communicate-with-sqlite-databases/ and reference this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405059/fmdb-resultset-into-dictionary

Comment: Could you send me an example project?

Comment: I tested your code, I create a table with 2 rows, and the php show the 2 rows. How many rows do you have? Maybe is a problem with the size of **results**.

Comment: Sorry I edited my question. It is showing the correct number of rows I am battling the ordering now.

Comment: OH! ok.. But do you agree with me that the line requestdata = ... need to go out of the while statement.

The problem with the order is that: **It is a dictionary**, so it is a hash table. 
Let me see if I can find a quick fix. 
Are you using FMDB library a lot?

Comment: I need to get to the lab in the morning I don't have a Mac here. I will try it then. You answered another one of my questions about posting a SQLite file, this question was an alternative for that. I would much rather send the sqlite file and do php alterations with that than this so I hope that works. And yes, I use FMDB throughout the app